# Do text / number input fields exist in matplotlib?

Tags: python, forms, matplotlib

Do text and / or number input fields exist for [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/)?

I have seen the widget [`Slider`](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider), but that is something different. I want a simple number input field.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009211/4124317) may be useful. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973758/how-do-i-make-matplotlib-open-a-box-for-user-comments) can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently exists no widgets that could be used to enter numbers as text. If you had a small selection of discrete numbers then you could use a [RadioButton](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RadioButtons) or you could use a slider as you've already suggested.

Your best would be to build a full GUI using [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). This would allow you to add whatever GUI elements you need. It's also possible to embed matplotlib graphs in Tkinter, as shown in the two examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html).

Comment: I would recommend using QT, looks better ;)

Comment: Hah yeah OK I do admit QT looks better. [wxpython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel) is another alternative.

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for the TextBox interactive widget, which was added in 2.1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.001)
ydata = t ** 2
initial_text = "t ** 2"
l, = plt.plot(t, ydata, lw=2)


def submit(text):
    ydata = eval(text)
    l.set_ydata(ydata)
    ax.set_ylim(np.min(ydata), np.max(ydata))
    plt.draw()

axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'Evaluate', initial=initial_text)
text_box.on_submit(submit)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If I understand [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6988) correctly, this will indeed be built in starting from version 2.1 (good job!). However, I strongly suggest removing `eval(text)` from that example, _especially_ since `text` is typed in by whoever's sitting in front of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I like QuadmasterXLII's answer and have something to add.
if using this with the update slider system you can use this to get the inner text.

```
# text box
t_box = plt.axes([0.05, 0.95, 0.8, 0.04])
file_text_box = TextBox(t_box, 'text', initial=init_txt)

def update(val)
    my_var = text_box.text_disp._text
```