# Is there a simple way to get a text-entry field in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, user-input, matplotlib-widget

I am writing a program using matplotlib and would like to have the option for the user to input text or numbers. There currently is not a text-entry widget in matplotlib however (to my knowledge).

Is there an easy way to get user text without either a) making them enter it through the terminal or b) writing a GUI/using a GUI package such as tkinter or pygtk?

For example, a simple library that would allow me to create a text-entry window.

Thanks.

Comment: If you exclude the two obvious solutions to the problem, what are you expecting as an answer? A text input by definition is a GUI element. If you exclude the use of a GUI element as a solution which requires a GUI element, you are contradicting yourself. Why not directly ask for a car without wheels?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contradicts itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you loosen the restriction of not using tkinter, a simple dialog is done with

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
w = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Title", "Please type comment")
```

A possible usage case can be found in this question: 
[How do I make matplotlib open a box for user comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973758/how-do-i-make-matplotlib-open-a-box-for-user-comments)