# Interacting with plot while user input prompt waits in console

Tags: matplotlib, input, interactive

I would like to be able to zoom/move/scale a plot (with the supplied buttons on the figure) during having an input prompt waiting in console.

At the moment i get the plot but i can not interact with it, not even close the figure, until i satisfy the user input

```
def Extract(var):
  do something

for i in range(var2):
  Extract(i)
  plt.plot(xax, yax)
  usrinp=input("This plot is called: ")
```

Any help will be greatly apprecieated!

Comment: The event loop will block until the input returns. That's essentially how python works. If you're looking for a way to get user input, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973758/how-do-i-make-matplotlib-open-a-box-for-user-comments) may be what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i will give it a try!